# How to install certificate for WebSphere having IIS as front end web server?

Tags: iis, certificate, websphere

I have installed an application inside WebSphere and I have connected IIS as a front end Web Server currently both in HTTP. (In WebSphere is visible on 9080 and on IIS on port 80).

My question is: how should I setup the SSL certificate to have HTTPS on my application?

I added the binding on IIS, but it did not worked.

Please advise.

Comment: What happens if you just follow a basic IIS guide for setting up SSL?

Comment: If I install the certificate on IIS, I get error 500 when browsing on HTTPS. No errors logged on Windows Event viewer (Application and System) and no details displayed on web (Detailed errors enabled on Error Pages Section on IIS).